# Type Error: Unsupported operand types Int and NoneType

Tags: python, operand

Hey guys I am working on a python program and I keep getting errors returned from the loop which is supposed to just reprompt the user to enter a number. The problem I am having is that it keeps returning a nonetype which cannot be used to operate on which I need to do in on of the other functions any help is appreciated. Thanks.

( Here's my code, Sorry ahead of time if it is not formatted correctly. )

```
def getTickets(limit):
   ticketSold=int(input("How many tickets were sold? "))
   if (ticketsValid(ticketSold,limit)):
        return ticketSold
   else:
        getTickets(limit)

#This function checks to make sure that the sold tickets are within the Limit of seats
def ticketsValid(sold,limit):

    if (sold>limit or sold<0):
        print ("ERROR: There must be tickets less than "+str(limit)+" and more than 0")
        return False
    return True
# This function calculates the price of the tickets sold in the section.
def calcIncome(ticketSold,price):
    return ticketSold*(price)
```

Comment: Where does the traceback say the error is? (What line?)

Comment: Change `getTickets(limit)` to `return getTickets(limit)` in the last line of `def getTickets`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in python: unsupported operand type(s) for \*: 'int' and 'NoneType'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724773/error-in-python-unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-nonetype)

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning `getTickets(limit)` inside your `else` block:

```
def getTickets(limit):
   ticketSold=int(input("How many tickets were sold? "))
   if (ticketsValid(ticketSold,limit)):
        return ticketSold
   else:
        return getTickets(limit)  # You need to use return here
```

Answer (score 1):

Python functions return `None` by default, if nothing is returned. You have an `else` clause that calls a function, but does nothing with it, and the function ends there, therefore if it goes down that control flow path, you will return `None` from that function.