# Error in python: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python

I am giving my input file:

```
2 1
```

I have written a code to find probabilities (specific to my work):

```
def fact(x):
    f=1
    if x > 0:
        for i in range(1,x + 1):
            f = f*i
        return f


def allele(s):
    n,k=[int(i) for i in s.split()]
    summ=0
    for i in range(n,((2**k)+1)):
            if i < (2**k +1):
                probability = (fact(2**k)/(fact(i)*fact((2**k)-i)))*(0.25**i)*(0.75**((2**k)-i))
                summ=summ+probability
    print summ

allele(open('D:\python\input.txt', 'r').read())
```

I am getting error at line where I am calculating the probabilities:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: At the very least, indent your code properly. We also don't want to sit there counting lines. Also, your line numbers might be different from ours. Posting the actual line is better than posting the line number.

Comment: Have you tested the function allele(s) with a range of inputs? If allele() fails in general, don't show us the rest of the code & the input data. If your problem is in reading the input file, narrow it down to that. (Hint: put in a lot of `print()` statements when you've newly defined a variable and are not sure the variable holds the right value.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `fact` function returns `None` for 0 instead of `1` because you indented
`return f` one extra level.

```
def fact(x):
    f = 1
    if x > 0:
        for i in range(1, x + 1):
            f *= i
    return f
```

Really, you should just use [`math.factorial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.factorial) for this.

```
from math import factorial as fact
```