# Python - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python

**The Problem**

I'm making a program that can tell you your grade.  I've gotten all the user inputs and now I need to do some calculations.  My problem arises when calculate_weighted_average is called.  It takes the arguments as integers (At least I think it does: I asked it to `print(x, y, z)` and it prints twice, once as the correct inputs for x,y,z and once as the correct input for x but it prints y and z as None) but it refuses to do the math operations I'm asking it to do.  Shouldn't the function be able to take the arguments and do this simple operation: `( x + y ) * z` ?
So for some reason y and z change to None which is what I need to fix!

**The Code**

```
def main():
    tests = get_initial_input("tests")
    assignments = get_initial_input("assignments")
    exercises = get_initial_input("exercises")
    labs = get_initial_input("labs")
    finals = get_initial_input("finals")
    testsp = get_percents(tests , "tests")
    assignmentsp = get_percents(assignments, "assignments")
    exercisesp = get_percents(exercises, "exercises")
    labsp = get_percents(labs, "labs")
    finalsp = get_percents(finals, "finals")
    testst = get_totals(tests, "tests")
    assignmentst = get_totals(assignments, "assignments")
    exercisest = get_totals(exercises, "exercises")
    labst = get_totals(labs, "labs")
    finalst = get_totals(finals, "finals")
    testss = get_scores(tests, "tests")
    assignmentss = get_scores(assignments, "assignments")
    exercisess = get_scores(exercises, "exercises")
    labss = get_scores(labs, "labs")
    finalss = get_scores(finals, "finals")
    testsz = calculate_weighted_average(testss, testst, testsp)
    assignmentsz = calculate_weighted_average(assignmentss, assignmentst, assignmentsp)
    exercisesz = calculate_weighted_average(exercisess, exercisest, exercisesp)
    labsz = calculate_weighted_average(labss, labst, labsp)
    finalsz = calculate_weighted_average(finalss, finalst, finalsp)
def get_initial_input(x):
    val = int(input("How many "+ x + " were there?    "))
    return val

def get_percents(x, string):
    if x > 0:
            xp = int(input("What percentage are "+ string + " weighted?       "))
            return xp

def get_totals(x, string):
    if x > 0:
            xt = int(input("How many total points available in the "+ string +" category?      "))
            return xt

def get_scores(x, string):
    total = 0
    for y in range(x):
            xs = int(input("Scores for "+ string +" ?:     "))
            total = total + xs
    return total
def calculate_weighted_average(x, y, z):
    print(x, y, z)
    this = ( x / y ) * z
    return this

main()
```

**The Traceback**

```
How many tests were there?    2
How many assignments were there?    0
How many exercises were there?    0
How many labs were there?    0
How many finals were there?    0
What percentage are tests weighted?       20
How many total points available in the tests category?      20
Scores for tests ?:     20
Scores for tests ?:     20
40 20 20
0 None None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assignment7.py", line 61, in <module>
    main()
  File "assignment7.py", line 23, in main
    assignmentsz = calculate_weighted_average(assignmentss, assignmentst, assignmentsp)
  File "assignment7.py", line 49, in calculate_weighted_average
    this = ( x / y ) * z
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: Your get_totals and get_percents functions will return None if the condition fails

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type Error: Unsupported operand types Int and NoneType](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416093/type-error-unsupported-operand-types-int-and-nonetype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function

```
def get_totals(x, string):
  if x > 0:
        xt = int(input("How many total points available in the "+ string +" category?      "))
        return xt
```

returns `None` when `x` is less than or equal to zero. This value later propagates to numerical expression in `calculate_weighted_average` and breaks it. 
Fix this and other functions to always return a number or throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust your `get_totals` and `get_percents` to return an `int` even if their conditions fail. As is, if either of their conditions are not met - `None` will be returned.

For example:

```
def get_percents(x, string):
    xp = 0
    if x > 0:
        xp = int(input("What percentage are "+ string + " weighted?       "))
    return xp
```

Also:

```
def get_totals(x, string):
    xt = 0
    if x > 0:
        xt = int(input("How many total points available in the "+ string +" category?      "))
    return xt
```